# Cycle2 calculates false margins in slideshow

Tags: javascript, html, css

I use the JQuery slider [Cycle2](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/) to center the images horizontally and vertically (testing on http://www.kadirkara.de/gs).

At some point the plugin calculates false margins bringing the images to the right bottom of the page.

My HTML:

```
<div class="cycle-slideshow" data-cycle-fx=fadeOut data-cycle-timeout=500 data-cycle-speed=200 data-cycle-center-horz=true data-cycle-center-vert=true>
    <img src="images/Gregor_Szinyai_Haus_Auwaeter_01.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/Gregor_Szinyai_Haus_Auwaeter_02.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/Gregor_Szinyai_Haus_Auwaeter_03.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/Gregor_Szinyai_Haus_Auwaeter_04.jpg" alt="">
    <img src="images/Gregor_Szinyai_Haus_Auwaeter_05.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

My CSS:

```
.cycle-slideshow { 
width: 80%;
margin: 1.2em auto !important;
}

.cycle-slideshow img {
max-width: 100% !important;
}
```

I don’t know but I think the problem could be somewhere in the `center.min.jsm` but I’m unfortunately not that skilled with Javascript.

```
function r() {
    var i = e(this),
        n = t.container.width(),
        s = t.container.height(),
        o = i.outerWidth(),
        l = i.outerHeight();
    t.centerHorz && n >= o && i.css("marginLeft", (n - o) / 2), t.centerVert && s >= l && i.css("marginTop", (s - l) / 2)
}
if (t.centerHorz || t.centerVert) {
    var c, a;
    e(window).on("resize orientationchange", n), t.container.on("cycle-destroyed", s), t.container.on("cycle-initialized cycle-slide-added cycle-slide-removed", function () {
        n()
    }), l()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, seems that adding the [progressive image load](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle2/demo/progressive.php) solves my problem very well.

If someone comes up with the same question.